# How to see the inequality $\lvert e^{itn} - e^{it} \rvert/n \leq 2/n $

Tags: calculus

The situation might be a bit ad-hoc with the $t$ and $n$ , however they are real numbers, and $i$ is $\sqrt{-1}$

$\lvert e^{itn} - e^{it} \rvert/n \leq 2/n$

i don't see how the equality can be  derived,maybe someone could help me

Answer (score 4):

The difference of two complex numbers with modulus $1$ cannot exceed $2$ in absolute value.

Comment: Triangle's Inequality.